# Nativescript : Select a level from Listview

Tags: android, listview, nativescript

I want to get a Level text when the listview (i.e,that level) is tapped.I'm able to get the index of that level.But I can not get the level text field.

**View:**

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ categoryList }}" itemTap="brand">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ category }}" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"  />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

**Js Controller:**

```
function getBrand() {

 user.register();

}   

exports.brand=function (args){ 
    item=args.index;

    //what to put here to be able to get the level text property

    user.register(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: You can put the tap listener to the label inside and get the reference through `args`:

In XML:

```
    <ListView items="{{ categoryList }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ category }}" tap="brand"/>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Then in js:

```
exports.brand = function(args) {
    item = args.object;
    var text = item.text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Mr. Dinh Le,It's acting strangely.Sometimes it's working for the last level.sometimes for the middle one.sometimes,not working at all.

Comment: The problem is I have to click on the text.Otherwise,it will not work.

Comment: Wrap all the UI inside `ListView.itemTemplate` into a Stacklayout. Then `args.object` will be the reference of that layout. You will set an `id` for label then get the label by `getViewById`. After that you can get the text

Comment: could you please explain with an example?It will be helpful.

Comment: your XML will be like this: `<StackLayout tap="brand"> <Label id="test" /> </StackLayout>`. Then `var layout = args.object`, finally `var label = layout.getViewById("test")`. You get label, you will get label.text